# hazelcast dynamic member addition now working by extending DiscoveryStrategyFactory

Tags: hazelcast

1.extended DiscoveryStrategyFactory .
did configuraton in hazelcast.xml   :

```xml
<discovery-strategies>
    <!-- class equals to the DiscoveryStrategy not the factory! -->
    <discovery-strategy enabled="true" class="simple_server.SuiteUtilDiscoveryStrategy">
        <properties>
            <property name="site-domain">cluster.local</property>
        </properties>
    </discovery-strategy>
</discovery-strategies>
```

added `com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory` in `main/resources` and added following line in it:

```
simple_server.SuiteUtilDiscoveryStrategy
```

2.but getting following exception :

> Caused by: com.hazelcast.config.properties.ValidationException:
> There is no discovery strategy factory to create 'DiscoveryStrategyConfig{properties={site-domain=cluster.local}, className='simple_server.SuiteUtilDiscoveryStrategy', discoveryStrategyFactory=null}' Is it a typo in a strategy classname? Perhaps you forgot to include implementation on a classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have both implementations - the factory and the strategy itself.

Put your **factory class name** into the `META-INF/services/com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory` service provider file.

Put your **strategy class name** into the `hazelcast.xml` configuration.

You can find more details in [Hazelcast documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.1/extending-hazelcast/discovery-spi#discovery-strategy) and the [code samples](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/v5.1.2/spi/discovery).

Comment: 1.working on local by downloading example from link.                                                                         2.but when tried to form cluster by running on another server , cluster of two members is not forming.